# How to invoke Mule's file-inbound endpoint from Command Line Interface (CLI) using curl?

Tags: curl, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to move/upload multiple files from source to destination (can be anything e.g. FTP or File outbound etc..) by using the below flow

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="f1">
            <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="f2">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>

  <flow-ref name="flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\outputfile" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

</flow>
```

The reason for doing in this way is that I want to invoke the job from CLI(Command Line Interface) using CURL.

But I am receiving the below error

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete.
>   One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.    at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
>   Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 11 in XML
>   document from URL
>   [file:/D:/MuleStudioExperiment/FileTransferUsingHTTP/.mule/apps/test/test.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content
>   of element 'flow' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
>   (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException:
>   Line 11 in XML document from URL
>   [file:/D:/MuleStudioExperiment/FileTransferUsingHTTP/.mule/apps/test/test.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content
>   of element 'flow' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException:
>   Line 11 in XML document from URL
>   [file:/D:/MuleStudioExperiment/FileTransferUsingHTTP/.mule/apps/test/test.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content
>   of element 'flow' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.    at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
>     ... 11 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 11 in XML document from URL
>   [file:/D:/MuleStudioExperiment/FileTransferUsingHTTP/.mule/apps/test/test.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content
>   of element 'flow' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleApplicationContext.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
>     at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11;
>   columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow'
>   is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.    at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1" initialState="stopped">
  <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

  <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\outputfile" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="flow2">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/start" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>

  <expression-component>
    app.registry.filePickupFlow.start();
  </expression-component>

  <set-payload value="File successfully copied" />

</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file endpoints are resource based endpoints (such as ftp and sftp endpoints) as opposed to event based endpoints (i.e. jms and vm) or tcp based endpoints (i.e. tcp, http, udp, etc)

For this reason the approach you are implementing won't fit your use case. If you need to load a file on demand (i.e. when you hit an http endpoint) you should refactor your flow and use the [mule-module-file-utils](http://javaduke.github.com/mule-module-file-utils/mule/fileutils.html). This module need to be added as a maven dependency or installed in Studio. You can do that by cloning the [git repo](https://github.com/javaduke/mule-module-file-utils) and then you can install the generated update site zip file following [these instructions](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Additional+Cloud+Connectors)

Once you did that your flow will look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:fileutils="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/fileutils" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/fileutils http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/fileutils/3.3/mule-fileutils.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd ">
    <fileutils:config name="Fileutils" doc:name="Fileutils"/>
    <flow name="FileCopier" doc:name="FileCopier">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="copy-file" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <scripting:transformer doc:name="Script">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[def dir = new File("/" + message.getInboundProperty('http.relative.path'))
log.info(dir.getPath())
return Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles())]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="fileNumber" value="#[payload.size()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
            <fileutils:copy-file config-ref="Fileutils" destinationName="#[message.payload.getName()]" destinationPath="/tmp/out/" fileName="#[message.payload.getName()]" filePath="#[message.payload.getParentFile().getPath()]" fileAge="0" doc:name="Fileutils"/>
        </foreach>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars['fileNumber'] + ' file copied']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
        </flow>
      </mule>
```

If you don't want to use the fileutils module you can replace it with a scripting component that implements the file copy logic

Now this flow can be invoked using the following curl command

curl http://${hostname}:8081/copy-file/${path_to_directory_to_copy}

The documentation about curl is available [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: The question was how to invoke it from CLI? Could you please detail about it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: The prefix "file-utils" for element "file-utils:config" is not bound.

Comment: Moreover, The http-inbound endpoint is the trigger and then the file(s) needs to be move to the destination. I know only the source folder name and the destination folder name. And no specific file name is know to me...Is there any other easy way?

Comment: I've improved my answer based on you comments